# How can I integrate an API from a website in Java?

Tags: java, html, api, intellij-idea, web-applications

My question is very concise. I have an API from RapidApi and I am looking to make a interactive Web Application. How can I integrate the API into Java in order to get access to all the methods that the API provides? Thank you.

Comment: "My question is very concise.".  No, it's actually hopelessly broad.  There are many, many alternatives.  There is no one, simple answer.  FIRST QUESTION: Are you accessing this API as a "user" (interactively), or as a "back end service"?  Who/what is the "client"?  NEXT QUESTION: are you familiar with (or are you willing to learn) frameworks like Spring Boot (if back-end)?  Choice of "language" (e.g. "Java") should actually be one of your LAST questions...

Comment: What do you mean by "I have an API" ? You need to provide details. API is just very general term without any correlation on how this API is provided.

Answer (score 3):

The API will most probably be a REST API. Have a look at https://restfulapi.net/ for background info.

The process of interacting with a REST API is called "consuming" the API.

Basically you just launch a HTTP request to the API, and the result is a JSON data structure.

The details of the HTTP Requests (URL, HTTP methods to use, and data to send), and the JSON return format are documented by the API.

Although it can be done without using any specific framework, it is probably easier with a framework like Spring.

If you know the basic concepts of Spring you could follow one of their guides about this topic: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

Comment: The OP hasn't given any clue what specific API he's looking at, or how he intends to use it. So we "don't know".   But  I think you're pointing him in the right direction - your suggestions are definitely useful.